# convert html tags to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My ajax call returns a strings where my first string will be code like this

```
 response[0]=2
```

and

```
 response[1]= Enter the reasons the application is being returned,<br><br><span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">* Caution! The text of this Message will be included in notices sent to the applicant *</span>
```

and i am assigning this to the id of my input tag like this

```
document.getElementById('messageHint').value = response[1] ;
```

But it doesnt render these `<br>` and `<span>` tags in to Html,instead it just shows them in the same format.How do i need to fix this issue.

I tried different apporches like `parse.Html()` and `$html.prop('outerHTML');` but neither one showed me the desired out put.

Comment: maybe `document.getElementById('messageHint').innerHTML = response[1];` ?

Comment: `.value` is not appropriate place to drop HTML.    .innerHTML or .innerText (don't) -- are the more applicable.

Comment: If you use jQuery why don't you just `$('#messageHint').html(response[1])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `document.getElementById('messageHint').innerHTML` instead.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2prurvsk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can give only one style to one placeholder like this:

 <style>

 input::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-size: 16pt; color: #555; }
 input::-moz-placeholder { font-size: 16pt; color: #555; }
 input:-ms-input-placeholder { font-size: 16pt; color: #555; }
 input:-moz-placeholder { font-size: 16pt; color: #555; }  

 input.other::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-size: 12pt; color: red; }
 input.other::-moz-placeholder { font-size: 12pt; color: red; }
 input.other:-ms-input-placeholder { font-size: 12pt; color: red; }
 input.other:-moz-placeholder { font-size: 12pt; color: red; }

 </style>

 <input type="text" placeholder="Hello"></input>
 <input type="text" class="other" placeholder="Hello"></input>

 and yes, .innerhtml is used to put the content into a div, not into an input field. so that's not useful to you in anyway.
```